# not getting value in html from with javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am not getting value in the alert box I am trying to get all values by using function with onclick. It gave me an empty value so how do I get all value with this keyword.

form

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id='textid' />
  <button class="btn" type="submit" onclick="myfunc(this);">click</button>
</form>
```

function

```
function myfunc(el){
  let x = el.value;
  alert(x) }
```

Comment: the question here is which value do you want to have on click? by returning 'this' you return the button itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are alerting value of `button`, instead you should first get the `input` and then get its value using `.value` property

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");

function myfunc(el) {
  let x = input.value;
  alert(x)
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id='textid' />
  <button class="btn" type="submit" onclick="myfunc(this);">click</button>
</form>
```